# Lower bounding $(1-2^{-n})^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(1-2^{-n})^n \geq \frac{1}{2}$

My attempts:

I've first written $(1-2^{-n})^n=(\frac{2^n - 1}{2^n})^n=\frac{(2^n - 1)^n}{2^{n^2}}$. I've tried using the binomial theorem and lower bounding the numerator, or writing the numerator as $(1+2+...+2^{n-1})$, but it hasn't worked. I've also tried analyzing the real-valued function $(1-2^{-x})^x$, but its derivatives are too complicated to analyze.

What else can I do in order to prove the statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$$(1-2^{-n})^n\ge 1-n2^{-n},$$
so all one needs is to prove that
$$n2^{-n}\le\frac12,$$
equivalently
$$n\le 2^{n-1}$$
etc.